# How to add a regular in-line style along with conditional in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to add a width along with a conditional style:

```
<input>
style={{width: "260px"}, array.indexOf(index) >= 0 ? {border: '1px solid red'} : {} }
</input
```

However, I can't see any changes I make to the `width` part. How can we add both conditional and regular inline styles together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spread operator to combine multiple styles as below:

```
<div style={{...{width: "260px"}, ...array.indexOf(index) >= 0 ? {border: '1px solid red'} : {} }}>
```